# How to Identify currency note using color?

Tags: c++, opencv

How to use Open CV to detect the color of the currency note.I'm going to identify the currency note using the color.

Comment: You're going to do the identification, but we have to provide the code? Try to do it yourself, and if you get stuck, post that specific code here. SO is not a "give me the code" site.

Comment: Problem is not with the coding.I drew the histogram and i got expected result.But there are currency notes with the color of red and purple.So I can't differentiate them as red and purple.I'll try to distinguish them.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate which color occurs the most in an image by using OpenCV's [histogram function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#calchist), then picking the highest value. Alternatively, you could rescale the image to 1x1 pixels and pick that color (which should be the average color).

However, identification using color alone is unlikely to give results that are precise enough for any use. American banknotes are all the same color, and it's not much better with Euro notes: a dirty €20 can be as gray as a €5 (and €200 and €100 are pretty similar).

Comment: thanks.I drew the histogram and i got expected result.But there are currency notes with the color of red and purple.So I can't differentiate them as red and purple.If u have any idea please help . Thanks